# Deploying socketio project on internet

Tags: javascript, heroku, websocket, socket.io, netlify

---

App.js

```
const socket = io();

socket.on('message', text => {

    const el = document.createElement('li');

    el.innerHTML = text;

    document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(el);

});

document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {

    const text = document.querySelector('input').value;

    socket.emit('message', text);

};
```

Index js

```
const http = require('http').createServer();

const io = require('socket.io')(http, {

    cors: { origin: "*" }

});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('message', (message) => {

        console.log(message);

        io.emit('message', `${socket.id.substr(0, 2)} said ${message}`);

    });

});

const PORT = 1234; // Allow dynamic port assignment for deployment

http.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on :${PORT}`));
```

Hi I wan to deploy this on to the internet but what should I add in io() parameters while deploying

While on the local I was using ws://localhost.com:1234

It was working what should I use while deploying to the internet

I want to deploy it to the internet and don't know what to add to io parameters in the app.js
Zee

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `const socket = io();` gives an error to you while you use it on shared host website. I had this problem at past and i saw somewhere that socket.io doesnt support shared hostings like cpanel. Instead, You can use websocket.js